# Add and Display an Element that is Calculated from entities and Automatically Updates

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, datagrid

Thanks for any help and glad to update and edit this question as answers and comments come in. Code has been shortened for hopefully easier reading.

I'm trying to implement MVVM in WPF using Entity Framework 6 database first.

I can currently retrieve data, perform CRUD and display individual columns as I want in a data grid. My viewmodel implements INotifyPropertyChanged and ICommand.

The (simplified) entity model from the database is:

```
public Weight
    {
        public decimal Benchmark_Weight { get; set; }
        public decimal Security_Weight { get; set; }
    }
```

And a public property on the model that is contained in the viewmodel:

```
public ObservableCollection<Weight> Weights
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
```

Then I instantiate the entity framework instance in the constructor of the viewmodel to retrieve the data and set to the local weights.

```
public WeightsViewModel()
        {
            _context = new BenchMarkEntities();
            _context.Weights.Load();
            this.Weights = _context.Weights.Local;
         }
```

Overall I want to display additional, automatically updating, data that is calculated from each row in the entity model. Basically, Active_Weight = Security_Weight - Benchmark_Weight.

So for example I'd have a datagrid with the entities from the model and then either in the same datagrid, another datagrid or even any itemscontrol that would display the collection of calculated data and it would automatically update when I updated Security_Weight or Benchmark_Weight in the datagrid.

I'm able to initially retrieve and display the calculated data through two different processes.

The first process is add a partial class to the entity model:

```
public partial class Weight
    {
        public decimal ActiveWeight
        {
            get { return Security_Weight - Benchmark_Weight; }
        }
    }
```

Then bind to this property in the view.

The other process is :

0.5) I Don't change the entity model.
1)Create a method to retrieve data from the entity model:

```
ObservableCollection<decimal> Retrieve()
{
    ObservableCollection<decimal> temp = new ObservableCollection<decimal>();
    foreach (var item in Weights)
    {
        temp.Add(item.Security_Weight - item.Benchmark_Weight);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

2) Call it in the constructor of the viewmodel:

```
 public WeightsViewModel()
        {
            _context = new BenchMarkEntities();
            _context.Weights.Load();
            this.Weights = _context.Weights.Local;
            ActWeight2 = Retrieve();
        }
```

3) assign to an additional property in the viewmodel:

```
public ObservableCollection<decimal> ActWeight2
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
```

But I can see the second process is flawed because if Retrieve is called you then add more items.

Here is the XAML:

```
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="SecurityWeight" Binding="{Binding Security_Weight}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="BenchmarkWeight" Binding="{Binding Benchmark_Weight}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ActiveWeight" Binding="{Binding ActiveWeight}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ActWeight2}"/>
```

Issue: when I make updates, the calculated data doesn't update on the display.

Any guidance on how to do this would be most appreciated.

Rye

Comment: Your calculated property is definitely the way to go. Is your problem from there that the values aren't updated for the `ActiveWeight` when you change the `SecurityWeight` and `BenchmarkWeight`?

Comment: @Shoe Yes. Part of what is unclear is how or where to bind so that changes to Security_Weight and Benchmark_Weight are immediately shown in Active_Weights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to create a viewmodel for `Weight` and then implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on this viewmodel. Your viewmodel containing your `ObservableCollection` then contains a list of viewmodels. Your XAML remains unchanged. This will allow INPC to flow to your view without clogging up your model class.

The viewmodel containing the "list" of weights.

```
public class WeightsListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<WeightViewModel> Weights
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public WeightsListViewModel()
    {
        _context = new BenchMarkEntities();
        .Load();
        this.Weights = _context.Weights.Select(w => new WeightViewModel(w));
    }
}
```

The viewmodel containing a single weight.

```
public class WeightViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public decimal Benchmark_Weight 
    { 
        get{ return _weight.Benchmark_Weight; } 
        set
        { 
            _weight.Benchmark_Weight = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Benchmark_Weight");
            OnPropertyChanged("ActiveWeight");
        }
    }

    public decimal Security_Weight 
    { 
        get{ return _weight.Security_Weight; } 
        set
        { 
            _weight.Security_Weight = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Security_Weight");
            OnPropertyChanged("ActiveWeight");
        }
    }

    public decimal ActiveWeight
    {
        get { return Security_Weight - Benchmark_Weight; }
    }

    private Weight _weight;
    public WeightViewModel(Weight weight){ _weight = weight; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I continued to investigate the issue I found a NuGet package called PropertyChanged.Fody. This adds INotifyPropertyChanged to the auto-generated class and OnPropertyChanged to each property in the class. I'll try to give your answer a go.